# Lock CD/DVD drive (prevent eject)

Tags: data-cd, lock

On my laptop the eject button for the CD/DVD drive is placed in a very
unfortunate position and I hit it a dozen times per day and the tray pops out.
I found many solutions which seemed to work for other people:

From `man eject`:

> -i on | 1 | off | 0
>
> This option controls locking of the hardware  eject  button.  When
>      enabled, the drive will not be ejected when the button is pressed.
>      This is useful when you are carrying a laptop in a bag or case and
>      don't want it to eject if the button is inadvertently pressed.

This seems to be exactly what I need. `eject -i on` successfully returns:

```
CD-Drive may NOT be ejected with device button
```

However, hitting the device button still ejects the drive. As suggested in
[another answer](https://superuser.com/a/71946/105023) invoking

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/dev/cdrom/lock
```

did not help either, `lock` already contains 1. The information from
`/proc/sys/dev/cdrom/info` suggests that locking is possible:

```
drive name:            sr0
drive speed:           24
drive # of slots:      1
Can close tray:        1
Can open tray:         1
Can lock tray:         1
Can change speed:      1
Can select disk:       0
Can read multisession: 1
Can read MCN:          1
Reports media changed: 1
```

The [cdctl tool](https://github.com/unicast/cdctl) is not in the Debian
repository and it does not build on my system.

How do I lock my drive so that hitting the hardware switch on the drive would no pop out the drive?

Comment: If you mount a CD-ROM, does it lock the drive? Can you see anything different in `/proc/sys/dev/cdrom`?

Comment: If a filesystem on the CD is mounted the locking with `eject` works. But not if it's not mounted or without media in drive. The contents of `/proc/sys/dev/cdrom` don't change.

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: @slm Debian GNU/Linux unstable with kernel 3.5.0

Answer (score 2):

I compiled [cdctl](http://cdctl.sourceforge.net/) some time ago for Fedora/CentOS. I've taken that compilation and converted to a .deb file. [cdctl](http://cdctl.sourceforge.net/) is the only application I've found that does a reliable job of locking/unlocking the CD/DVD eject button.

Feel free to give it a try.

- [My original blog post discussing cdctl and it's compilation on Fedora/CentOS](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/4683/one-liner-locking-the-eject-button-cd-dvd-drive-under-fedora14-centos5-laptop/)
- [cdctl 0.15-1 x64 build for Debian/Ubuntu](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/cdctl_0.15-1.lamolabs.1_amd64.deb)

Commands to lock and unlock

```
# locks the tray
% cdctl -o1

# unlocks the tray
% cdctl -o0
```

Comment: With the patch I could compile it, but it does not work either. When I press the button the drive pops out.

Comment: Something must of changed with the newer kernels, it worked up to 2.6.35.14-106.fc14.x86_64 for me on Fedora 14. I tried it on my Ubuntu 12.10 system and it disables the ability of the eject command from working but not the drives button on front. I'll take a peak at the cdctl source when I get a chance.

Comment: Curious, did you recompile on Debian?

Comment: Yes, see comment under my question. I did not test interference with eject.

Comment: Not sure if you saw this Q&A, the issue with cdctl was resolved: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104791/how-can-i-disable-the-button-of-my-cd-dvd-drive

Comment: I tried the DISK_EJECT_REQUEST solution and `eject` works as expected. Maybe I should flag my question as a duplicate.

Comment: I voted it as a dup as well.