# How can I disable the button of my CD/DVD drive?

Tags: linux, data-cd, audio-cd, eject

Up until Fedora 14 I was successfully using [`cdctl`](http://cdctl.sourceforge.net/) to enable/disable the CD/DVD eject button on my laptop (Thinkpad T410). Sadly it has stopped working now.

I've consulted the methods discussed in these 2 questions:

- [disable cd/dvd button on linux laptop (ubuntu)](https://superuser.com/questions/71939/disable-cd-dvd-button-on-linux-laptop-ubuntu)
- [Disable the DVD eject button on a Thinkpad running Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/524945/disable-the-dvd-eject-button-on-a-thinkpad-running-linux/687231#687231)

None of which have worked for me. So I turn back to `cdctl` to see if we can't fix what's broken with it, since it's worked for so long.

#### Debugging the issue

So starting with `cdctl` switches I notice that most things seem to work just fine.

#### Examples

These things work.

*ejects the drive*

```
$ cdctl -e
```

*list capabilities*

```
$ cdctl -k
Tray close             : 1
Tray open              : 1
Can disable eject      : 1
Selectable spin speed  : 1
Is a jukebox           : 0
Is multisession capable: 1
Can read the MCN (UPC) : 1
Can report media change: 1
Can play audio discs   : 1
Can do a hard reset    : 1
Can report drive status: 1
```

According to that list `cdctl` even thinks that it can enable/disable the eject button.

> ```
> Can disable eject      : 1
> ```

So I continue on with debugging the issue.

#### Debugging cdctl

So I figure lets do an `strace` on `cdctl` to see if it can shed some light on what's going on.

```
$ strace cdctl -o1
...
brk(0)                                  = 0x1371000
open("/dev/cdrom", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/dev/cd", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/dev/scd0", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/dev/sr0", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK)   = 3
ioctl(3, CDROM_LOCKDOOR, 0x1)           = 0
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Curiously it seems like `cdctl` thinks it's disabling the button.

```
$ strace cdctl -o1
ioctl(3, CDROM_LOCKDOOR, 0x1)           = 0

$ strace cdctl -o0
ioctl(3, CDROM_LOCKDOOR, 0)             = 0
```

**NOTE:** If I understand this right, the return of a 0 means it was successful.

One thing that caught my eye here was the list of devices that `cdctl` is attempting to interact with. So I thought "what if I try these devices with `eject`"?

#### eject command

One of the other commands I used to use years ago was the `eject` command to interact with the CD/DVD device. I noticed that this command also now has a similar named switch:

```
$ eject --help
 -i, --manualeject <on|off>  toggle manual eject protection on/off
```

#### Example

```
$ eject -i 1 /dev/sr0
eject: CD-Drive may NOT be ejected with device button

$ eject -i 0 /dev/sr0
eject: CD-Drive may be ejected with device button
```

So `eject` too thinks that it's disabling the button, yet it isn't either. Using `strace` here I see the same system calls:

```
$ strace eject -i 1 /dev/sr0 |& grep ioctl
ioctl(3, CDROM_LOCKDOOR, 0x1)           = 0

$ strace eject -i 0 /dev/sr0 |& grep ioctl
ioctl(3, CDROM_LOCKDOOR, 0)             = 0
```

So now I'm wondering if UDEV or something else is potentially blocking or taking ownership of device?

Thoughts?

Comment: I also have a T410, and often find myself hitting the CD drive eject button when I don't mean to. I'll be interested to see if this gets resolved.

Comment: Is the button still working when the Disk in that drive is mounted?

Comment: I feel you pain, I had the same problem: [Lock CD/DVD drive (prevent eject)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/59707/12779). I found no solution and ended up removing the drive physically, since it was too annoying to have the drive pop out a dozen times per day. Good luck…

Comment: @Marco - see the answer!

Comment: @WhiteHotLoveTiger - see the answer!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***Thanks to @Affix's answer which gave me the right direction to head, I've figured out the solution to the problem.***

The problem is definitely caused by UDEV as you've guessed. The issue is this line that is in most UDEV files related to the cdrom drive.

#### Example

On Fedora 19 there is the following file, `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-cdrom_id.rules`. In this file is the following line which is co-opting the eject button for CD/DVD devices.

```
ENV{DISK_EJECT_REQUEST}=="?*", RUN+="cdrom_id --eject-media $devnode", GOTO="cdrom_end"
```

You can work around the issue and disable UDEV's ability to co-opt the eject button by doing the following:

1. Make a copy of the file `60-cdrom_id.rules`

   ```
   $ sudo cp /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-cdrom_id.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/.
   ```
2. Edit this copied version of the file and comment out the line containing the string, `DISK_EJECT_REQUEST`.

   ```
   $ sudoedit /etc/udev/rules.d/60-cdrom_id.rules
   ```
3. Save the file and the change should be noticeable immediately!

The above solution fixes the problem for both `eject` and `cdctl`. So now the following commands work as expected:

*lock the drive*

```
$ eject -i on /dev/sr0
eject: CD-Drive may NOT be ejected with device button

-or-

$ cdctl -o1
```

*unlock the drive*

```
$ eject -i off /dev/sr0
eject: CD-Drive may be ejected with device button

-or-

$ cdctl -o0
```

Comment: @Marco - I'm confused what you're asking me, I didn't change the `/lib/` rule. I copied it to `/etc/udev/rules.d/` and made my own overriding version.

Comment: @Marco - NP, there's ample places to get confused and make mistakes 8-)

Comment: Thanks for this. Confirmed in current Debian stable (8/Jessie). Commenting out that line instantly removed my ability to, e.g., accidentally eject a Bluray while it's mounted or even playing. Gotta love how `udev` overrides expected behaviour elsewhere in Linux... But now I can let KDE handle deliberate ejection and stop worrying about accidents.

Answer (score 2):

Add the line:

```
DISC_EJECT_REQUEST
```

to the CD ROM udev rules. This will enable you to lock with:

```
eject -i
```

Comment: The line actually needed to be removed, at least in my case on Fedora 19.

Comment: Same here. Even so: Add it to which file? between which other lines? Is that the entire line? Surely that's not syntactically valid for `udev`? etc. - poor answer.