# Commands to read and eject CD?

Tags: data-cd

My laptop is a Thinkpad T400 and the OS is Ubuntu 12.04.

I find I have a problem where the CD-RW on my laptop sometimes doesn't read the CD, following some flashing light and sound, after I inserted the CD inside. I press the button to eject the CD, but there is no response. It happens especially when I have some external device using a USB port of the laptop. But sometimes it works as normal.

I wonder if there are some Linux commands to force the CD to be read and to be ejected?

What might be the  problem? The OS, or the CD Reader?

Comment: As a side note, you can lock/unlock the eject button feature using this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104791/how-can-i-disable-the-button-of-my-cd-dvd-drive. I constantly bump it on my T410. The tool ref'd in that post `cdctl` can also toggle the eject.

Answer (score 4):

First of all you have to mount the device, using GUI or command mount.

```
# mount -t iso9660 -o ro /dev/cdrom /cdrom
```

or

```
# mkdir /mnt/cdrom
# mount -t iso9660 -o ro /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom
```

eject is the command to eject the CD/DVD drive.

```
# eject
```

Comment: On some systems you have to specify the basename or full path to `eject` if `/dev/cdrom` is not the CD drive or a symlink to it.

Comment: Thanks! The output to the first command is `mount: special device /dev/cdrom does not exist`, and the output to the second one is `eject: tried to use /mnt/cdrom as device name but it is no block device` and `eject: unable to find or open device for: cdrom`

Comment: Try to run the following: # cd /dev; ls cd*

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 12.04, for me this works:

```
eject /dev/sr0
```

Comment: Welcome to U & L SE. Can you please elaborate more on your answer? Also, the other answer has already discussed `eject` option.

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on a Lenovo Z510 laptop. The command: "eject /dev/sr0" works. You do not need to mount. Using just "eject" does not work.